# suppose P is a probability function defined in the real line R, prove these two points

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

$P([0,\infty) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P([0, n])$
and
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P([n,\infty])=0$

I have been trying to construct sequences $F_n = E_n/(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}E_i)$ but I can't seem to make the left side of the first equation be open, it ends in $[0, \infty]$ form.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n [0,k] = [0,\infty)$ see here for example: [Prove that the Union of [1/n,n] = (0,∞) from n=1 to ∞](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1467577/439353)

---

Let $A_0 = {0}$ and $A_n = (n-1,n]\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N$. Let $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^n A_i$.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P [B_n] &= \mathbb P \left[\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^n A_i\right]\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P [B_n] &= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P \left[\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^n A_i\right]\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P [0,n]&= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \mathbb P [A_i]\\
&=\mathbb P \left[\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^n [n-1,n] \right]\\
&=\mathbb P \left[ [0,\infty) \right]\\
\end{align*}
Where the [last equality is because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467577) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n [0,k] = [0,\infty)$

2. To prove: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} P([n,\infty])=0$

Let the sample space $S = [0,\infty)$. Then if $A_n = [n-1,n)$ and $B_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^n A_i =[0,n)$, then $B_n^c = [n,\infty)$

\begin{align*}
[n,\infty)&=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n [k,\infty)\\
&=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n B_k^c\\
\mathbb P ([n,\infty)) &= \mathbb P\left[\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n B_k^c\right]\\
&=\mathbb P\left(\enspace\left[\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n B_k\right]^c\enspace\right) \\
&=\mathbb P\left(S \bigg\backslash\enspace\left[\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n B_k\right]\enspace\right) \\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P ([n,\infty))&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(S \bigg\backslash\enspace\left[\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n B_k\right]\enspace\right)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(S \bigg\backslash\enspace\left[\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n B_k\right]\enspace\right)
\end{align*}
But $S = [0,\infty)$ and $\left[\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n B_k\right] = [0,\infty)$

Therefore $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P ([n,\infty)) = \mathbb P[\varnothing] = 0$$

Comment: such an elegant answer easy to understand. Thank you so much